# Group by alternative

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table , that has a generic set of actions for EVERY user.

However if there is a user that needs to have a unique action, that replaces an existing action,  then in my query, I want to exclude the generic action.

So for example every logged in user gets two actions OPEN or CLOSE based on the table below.

SELECT ActionID, ActionCode FROM Actions

```
ActionID,  ActionCode,      LoginID. 
OPEN       Open contract    NULL – Generic Open Operation
CLOSE      Close Contrct    NULL  -- Generic Close Operation
```

A new user has a very specific OPEN case so if I add a row to the Action table

```
ActionID, ActionCode,    LoginID. 
OPEN      Open contract   NULL  – Generic Open Operation
CLOSE     Close Contrct   NULL  - Generic Close Operation
OPEN1     Open1 contract  123   – Specific Open Operation only to user logged in as 123
```

So then I perform the following query

```
SELECT ActionID, ActionCode FROM Actions WHERE (LoginID = 123 OR LoginID is null)
```

I get

```
OPEN    Open contract   NULL    
CLOSE   Close Contrct   NULL    
OPEN1   Open1 contract  123
```

But I want

```
CLOSE   Close Contrct   NULL    
OPEN1   Open1 contract  123
```

Comment: Is there a `datetime` column or something else that shows how the rows should be ordered? And more important, is there any other column that indicates that these 3 rows (that you show here) are related between them  and with the specific id (=123), from the thousands of other rows of the table?

Comment: I think you should have some way of showing explicitly that OPEN1 is an acceptable substitute for OPEN.  We humans can intuit this from the names used but 'puters ain't so clever.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
with ActionX as (
   select
        ActionID, coalesce(LoginID,'_')) as LoginID, ActionCode
    from ActionTable
)
select
    a.ActionID,
    a.LoginID
    b.ActionCode
from (
   select
        ActionID, max(LoginID) as LoginID
    from ActionX t
    group by ActionID
) a
join ActionX  b
   on b.ActionID  = a.ActionID
  and b.LoginID   = a.LoginID
```